# Storing GenServer result from for loop

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to store the last result of a GenServer Call inside a for loop.
I can't really figure out how this should be correctly done.

```
def handle_info(:load_info, state) do
  infos = for info <- state.infos do
    {:ok, infos} = send(self(), {:info_link, info})
    infos
  end

  {:noreply, %{state | infos: infos}}
end

def handle_info({:info_link, info}, state) do    
  {:ok, pid} = Infos.Server.start_link({info})
  infos = Map.put(state.infos, info.name, info)

  {:reply, {:ok, state}, %{state | infos: infos}}
end
```

Comment: This is one of those questions where it is best for you to state the problem you are trying to solve. In this case, you are asking "how to do X" but doing X may not be the best solution to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 4):

`GenServer` is not a magic pot that produces resources out of the air. It’s a single Erlang process. It has *no concurrency inside*. A subsequent call to `handle_info`, even despite it’s asynchronous, will be put into process’ mailbox to be processed *only after the first call is returned*. [Here is a good reference](http://www.dalnefre.com/wp/2011/10/erlang-style-mailboxes/) on how Erlang process mailbox is organized in a nutshell.

That said, all calls to:

```
send(self(), {:info_link, info})
```

are put stacked into process’ mailbox to be processed *after* the current `handle_info` has returned.

To achieve the functionality you need, one should separate the code into two different processes, e.g. into two different `GenServer`s.